# PostgreSQL trigger which updates count in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update, sql-function

I am rather new to PostgreSQL and I am really stuck with an apparently simple task. I have a table with music albums and a table with bands features, including how many albums such band released in a specific time, let say between 1990 and 1995. So I need to create a trigger that keeps the bands tabe updated whenever I insert, delete or updaste the albums table.
These are the tables:

```
Album

id_album   id_band    year
1          1          1995
2          1          1985
3          2          1993
4          3          1998


Band

id_band   num_albums9095
1         1 
2         1 
3         0
```

So I have created the following function and trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_num_nineties()
RETURNS trigger AS $$ BEGIN
UPDATE band
SET num_albums_eighties = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM album
where album.year between 1990 and 1995
GROUP BY album.id_band);
END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_nineties_album_mod_album AFTER UPDATE ON album FOR EACH row EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_num_nineties();
```

But I would get a *subquery used as an expression returned more than one row message* anytime I try to update any value to test it.
Would anyone be so kind to help me see why I am goind in the wrong direction?

Comment: Generally a bad idea to store aggregates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *correlate* the subquery with the outer query:

```
update band b
set num_albums_eighties = (
    select count (*) 
    from album a
    where a.year between 1990 and 1995 and a.id_band = b.id_band
)                                        --^-- correlation --^--
```

While this technically works, it is still rather inefficient, because it resets the whole table when just one row in modified. You can restrict the rows with a `where` clause:

```
update band b
set num_albums_eighties = (
    select count (*) 
    from album a
    where a.year between 1990 and 1995 and a.id_band = b.id_band
)
where b.id_band in (old.band_id, new.band_id)
```

Comment: Many thanks, @GMB. I am going to try it and let you know if it works!